# android.R.id.content as container for Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

My situation is Activity A which contains Fragment B. I always implement it like this.

Layout for Activity A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Layout for Fragment B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_title"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works great, but if we open Android Device monitor and look at View Hierarchy:

[image]

So, I do not like that in my hierarchy there are two same useless FrameLayouts and I can cut my R.id.container. I do it like this:

onCreate(Bundle args) implementation in my Activity A:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, FragmentB.newInstance()).commit();
}
```

I just do not set content for my Activity and attach my Fragment B to system container android.R.id.content. This works great for me. I removed one useless include.

My question is it good practice to do this "hack". Could it crashs my application in any cases and what problems could I have after this implementation? May be somebody has useful experience in this question?

Thanks to all for good answers.

Comment: `same` no, android.R.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with it. Like you said: you dont need your extra R.id.content layout so... just don't add it with setContentView. There is even mention about it in official documentation of ActionBar: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

> Alternatively, if the tab content will fill the activity layout, then
>   your activity doesn't need a layout at all (you don't even need to
>   call setContentView()). Instead, you can place each fragment in the
>   default root view, which you can refer to with the
>   android.R.id.content ID

If you develop only for 14+ (because of native ActionBar) everything should be fine with it, but if you use support lib please read the points below.

### I. If you use Support Library revision lower than 19:

Important thing is: What is your min API level that you develop for?

If your app supporting API < 14 and you use AppCompat you must be aware the different behavior.
**android.R.id.content** is the part of screen where your application should display it's content.
On native API 14+ This is just part below ActionBar, because this part is supposed to display activity content.

In AppCompat, where there is no native support for ActionBar. **android.R.id.content** is the container of entire app screen. This means - including ActionBar, because ActionBar is emulated there and added as a standard view hierarchy. To solve this issue you have to check whether you are on API lower than 14 and use different id: **R.id.action_bar_activity_content**

You can create helper method to get correct id:

```
public static int getContentViewId() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ? android.R.id.content : R.id.action_bar_activity_content;
}
```

So if you are developing for 14+ this is perfectly fine solution. If you use custom ActionBar implementation (like AppCompat) you have to do this trick.

---

### II. If you use Support Library revision 19 (or greater):

It seems that this behavior was fixed in Support Library revision 19:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58108#c21

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java/#228

You can see that they replacing the old **R.id.action_bar_activity_content** with standard **android.R.id.content** (and the old android.R.id.content with NO_ID) for better compatibility! So if you use Support Lib r19 or greater (or just a native framework) you can just just android.R.id.content in both <14 and 14+ variants:)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help:)
I've also reorganized my answer a little bit + added link (and quote) to ActionBar documentation on top (there is mention about this particular case exactly)

Comment: This is weird. I used the android.R.id.content on support library v20, and it didn't work. only thing that worked is to use a layout file and use setContentView on it.

Comment: It seems this has been broken again in appcompat >= v22 (it was working for me on v21, but upgrading to v22 or v23 breaks, and putting in my own content FrameLayout fixes it)