# FrameLayout Shown Above AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a simple `CoordinatorLayout` with a `AppBarLayout` and `FrameLayout`, but the `FrameLayout` contents are being displayed over the `AppBarLayout` regardless of the layout_behavior attribute on the `FrameLayout`. I've tried adding that attribute elsewhere (like on my `RecyclerView`), but it's the same behavior.

**Here's a picture to show what I mean.**

[image]

Activitiy Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/checkins_recycler_view"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

How I add my fragment in my Activity:

```
final UserCheckinsFragment fragment = new UserCheckinsFragment();
    final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    UserCheckinsFragment.getArguments(arguments, items);
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment,
            UserCheckinsFragment.class.getName()).commit();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FrameLayout` ID (`@android:id/content`) in the xml and the container (`android.R.id.content`) in the `Fragment` transaction refer to the system ***root of layout***, then it is laid over the all screen.

To solve, use them without `android` prefix.

Answer (score 3):

add   `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the `RecyclerView` and it will work. The `app:layout_behavior` should be to the root of the layout's of your `Fragment`

Comment: Unfortunately adding that to the RecyclerView has the same behavior.

Comment: I had the same issue with the situation. I had to add `    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the root of Fragment's layout (in my case was  a RelativeLayout) which contained the RecyclerView among other stuff

Comment: So the root of my fragment's layout is the RecyclerView which I have listed in the original question. Adding the layout_behavior attribute to that didn't work (I'll update the question to reflect what I used). Maybe I'll try to add another container layout to see if it'll work. Worth a shot maybe, even if it is hacky.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24713989/4409113

> In `AppCompat`, there is no native support for `ActionBar`.
>   `android.R.id.content` ***is the container of entire app screen***. This means
>   - including `ActionBar`, because `ActionBar` is emulated there and added as a standard view hierarchy.

You may want to use(In the `Layout`):

```
android:id="@+id/content"
```

And(in `Java`):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content, fragment,
                UserCheckinsFragment.class.getName()).commit();
```

Then, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had the same problem and i fixed it by adding"app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"‌" into my layout parent which is linear layout and contain the RecylerView Layout and now it works correctly but i have an other problem that the button which is in the boutmn of the page disapear